# Bash: String manipulation terminate on whitespace

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a string variable `$LIBRARIES="abc.so.1 def.so.1 hij.so.3.1"` and I want to replace all the .so such that they look like this:

```
"abc.so* def.so* hij.so*"
```

How can I do this? I tried `NEW_LIBRARIES=${LIBRARIES//.so*/.so$star}` but it doesn't work. How can I tell it to end on whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
LIBRARIES="abc.so.1 def.so.1 hij.so.3.1"
NEW_ALL_LIBRARIES=$(sed 's/\.so[^ ]*/\.so\*/g' <<< "$LIBRARIES")
echo "$NEW_ALL_LIBRARIES"
```

**Output:**

```
abc.so* def.so* hij.so*
```

**Explanation:**

- `LIBRARIES="..."`: When assigning a string to a variable, the variable is not prefixed with `$`
- `NEW_ALL_LIBRARIES=$(...)`: The `$(...)` notation is called [command subsitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html); basically it spawns a new subshell to run whatever commands contained within, then returns the output to this new subshell's `stdout` (and here saving it to `NEW_ALL_LIBRARIES`).
- `sed`: invoke [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), the Streaming EDitor tool
- `'s/\.so[^ ]*/\.so\*/g'`: Use [regular expressions (regex)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match patterns and substitute. Let's break this syntax down a bit further:

  - `s/` "substitute"; For example: `s/A/B/g` replaces all occurrences of `A` with `B`
  - `\.so[^ ]*/`: Match any patterns that start with `.so`, and the `[^ ]*` part means "followed by zero or more non-space characters"
  - `\.so\*/`: Replace that with literally `.so*`
  - Some symbols such as `[`, `]`, `.` and `*` have special meaning in regex, so if you mean to use them literally, you just "escape" them by prefixing a `\`
  - `g`: Do so for all occurrences, not just the first.
- `<<< "$LIBRARIES"`: the `<<<` notation is called [herestring](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html): in this context it accomplishes the same thing as `echo "$LIBRARIES" | sed ...`, but it saves a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

or simpler

```
${LIBRARIES//.[0-9]/*}
```

the ones with 2 extensions will get 2 ** but that should be fine

Comment: If you turn on extended glob support (`shopt +s extglob`), you can use `${LIBRARIES//+(.[0-9])/*}`.